# CORS error while using Rest Get Api to consume Data

Tags: javascript, cors, xmlhttprequest, postman, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to consume data using XMLHttpRequest from cloud and getting the CORS error. Below is the code I am trying,

When I am using `"chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security"` it is working fine, but not without that:

```
function getSearchResults(){

    var data = null;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        console.log(this.readyState);
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    });
}
xhr.open("GET", "My url");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", localStorage.getItem("Tokens"));
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "b77db68c-749a-f452-3074-60aa33f2786e");
xhr.send(data);
...
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is a security mechanism which is not meant for you to overcome. If it's your own server that's being queried, you'd have to adjust these headers on server-side:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

CORS in a nutshell: An API decides where to accept requests from and how.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to set this on the server side. Are you using AWS or which kind of server?

Comment: I m using Oracle Visual Builder Cloud Service to host this, 
Is it something I have to add the Server URL on the requested source side?

Comment: then this should help: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/content-cloud/administer/enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors.html

Comment: Does this mean, i need to ask the target owner to add the server Url ?

Comment: if you don't have access, you have to ask them, right.